# ActiveRecord: Has_many inside another has_many - with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

So I am setting up a system of pages and apps, and app content. Where a page has_many :app_instances, and app_instances has_many :app_contents.

I have models:
page, app, app_instance, app_content

In my models:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_instances
end

class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
end

class AppInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :app_contents
end

class AppContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app_instance
  belongs_to :app
end
```

I'd like to have one object, where all the contents are under the individual contents live under the app instance... but is there a way to do this?

I setup this in one of my controllers:

```
@page = Page.includes(:app_instances).find(params[:id])
```

I can successfully debug @page.app_instances, but soon as I say @page.app_instances.app_contents i get an error. I am guessing this is just because i am missing the include within the include, but not sure how i write that, or even if that is "good practice"

I know i could probably do:

```
has_many :app_contents, :through => :app_instances
```

but id rather have the object organized with the instance holding the contents (that makes sense, right?)... so i could loop through all the instances, and print out the contents of the instance

Does my DB architecture make sense? or am I going at this the wrong way

Joel

Answer (score 1):

You can include nested using:

```
Page.includes(:app_instances=>[:app_contents])
```

But main reason you are getting an error is because, in `@page.app_instances.app_contents`
page.app_instances doesn't have any `app_contents`. You would be looking for an union of `app_contents` of all `app_instances` of `@page`

So it can be done via:

```
@page.app_instances.app_contents.each{|ai| (list || =[]) << ai.app_contents}
list.flatten!
```

OR

define `page has many app_contents through app_instances` relationship in your model.

The first case would run query for **each** app_instances , however with using *includes* as I mentioned earlier that would result in single query. The second case would result in a single join query joining app_contents, app_instances table

Comment: Yup.. It defines best your relationship of page and app_contents
 and query is better optimized actually..